# "Parent" of TextView in Android

Tags: android, parent-child

In Windows programming when you create a control or window you need to supply a **handle to parent** window which owns it:

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindow(
  LPCTSTR   lpClassName,
  LPCTSTR   lpWindowName,
  DWORD     dwStyle,
  int       x,
  int       y,
  int       nWidth,
  int       nHeight,
  HWND      hWndParent,
  HMENU     hMenu,
  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  LPVOID    lpParam
);
```

In Android, to create TextView in Java you need to do just:

```
TextView textview = new TextView(getContext());
```

Is there a concept of TextView "parent" in Android or does the context also refers to parent? However, there's no mention or use the word "parent" in Android's documentation for [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Comment: Rather than referencing an ancient Win16 API, you might wish to explain exactly what aspects of a "parent" concern you. What are the **specific** things that you expect a "parent" to do? Some of those things might be handled by the `Activity` or other `Context` passed into the widget constructor. Some of those things might be handled by the `Window` the widget is eventually applied to. Some of those things might be handled by some other container between the widget and the `Window` (e.g., `LinearLayout`).

Comment: Yes, context is similar concept.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am trying to better understand the different between context and parent. For example: I want to know what does the `context` do for TextView?

Comment: "I am trying to better understand the different between context and parent" -- you would have to define what "parent" means to you. "I want to know what does the context do for TextView?" -- primarily, it is a way of accessing resources used by the widget, such as background images.

Comment: @CommonsWare: It means a handle to window that owns or where the TextView is attached to. I want to clear something up, does accessing the resources include the drawable, layout and value (e.g. string) resources?

Comment: "does accessing the resources include the drawable, layout and value (e.g. string) resources?" -- yes. By "resources", I mean [Android's resource system](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html).